# Which file are actually taking care of "Logout" process? (killing sessions)

Tags: php, joomla-3.4

I am learning the basic concept of how to manage login process and sessions. I take it that to logout a user, you need to destroy the session created for him. I was trying to find out how joomla 3.4 handles "logout" action to verify whether I have correctly understand what I have learned. But I have trouble finding out which PHP file is actually taking care of the "logout" logic. Here is what I do:

Firstly, I think no matter what fancy(to me) library or framework Joomla is using, down to bottom, there should be a file receiving "$_POST" datas, so I searched `$_POST` among all PHP files in my site, and I found this file "libraries/legacy/request/request.php" with this function

```
Class JRequest{
    .....
    public static function getVar($name, $default = null, $hash = 'default', $type = 'none', $mask = 0)
    {
        // Ensure hash and type are uppercase
        $hash = strtoupper($hash);

        if ($hash === 'METHOD')
        {
            $hash = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        }

        $type = strtoupper($type);
        $sig = $hash . $type . $mask;

        // Get the input hash
        switch ($hash)
        {
            case 'GET':
                $input = &$_GET;
                break;
            case 'POST':
                $input = &$_POST;
                break;
            case 'FILES':
                $input = &$_FILES;
                break;
            case 'COOKIE':
                $input = &$_COOKIE;
                break;
            case 'ENV':
                $input = &$_ENV;
                break;
            case 'SERVER':
                $input = &$_SERVER;
                break;
            default:
                $input = &$_REQUEST;
                $hash = 'REQUEST';
                break;
        }
.....
```

It seems to me Joomla has integrated "$_POST" data processing into this function so whenever Joomla wants to deal with user input, it will call this function. So I continue to search `JRequest::getVar` among all PHP files, I found only 1 occurence, which is in `components/com_meida/views/medialist/view.html.php` line 64

```
$dirname = JRequest::getVar('folder', '', '', 'string');
```

This doesn't look like having anything to do with login/logout processing. So I widen my search to just `getVar`, although there are many occurences, none of them looks like relevant and this is where I got stuck.

Could you please not only point out the PHP file I am looking for but also tell me what is wrong with my approach? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`JRequest::getVar` is an old deprecated method to get global variables which is no longer used in Joomla 3.x

### Session:

Joomla has it's own framework which can be found here:

> libaries/joomla/

The file you're specifically looking for that deals with destroying the session is:

> libraries/joomla/session/session.php **line 682**

See  on Github here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/session/session.php#L682

As you can see, this calls `$this->_handler->clear();`, and the function for this is here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php#L243

This unsets and destroys the session

---

### Logout:

If you want to go further back before the session is dealt with, have a look at:

> administrator/components/com_login/controller.php **line 97**

Comment: TYVM.I still want to know when users click "logout", what kind of global variable was sent and sent to where. I was trying to backtrace from that `destroy()` function in session.php. But it was very hard for me to debug this file: First I changed the name of the function, then when I click 'logout' I got an error, so its confirmed that this function was called when logging out. Then I insert `echo 's';` into the `destroy()` as well as `var_dump(debug_backtrace())`, but none of them got any result to display on front end. I even try using j!dump to backtrace, but still got nothing.How debug it?