# When users click "logout", where is the global variable sent to?

Tags: joomla-3.4, user, login

[image]

Joomla Version: 3.4
Possible related extension: Community Builder

This is the form of a logout button on my site, the method being "post" means when users click "logout", a `$_POST` or `#_REQUEST` is being generated. I think no matter what libraries or framework Joomla is using, there should still be somewhere directly taking care of these variables. So I search `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` among all *.php files, but I couldn't find anything that seem to be what I am seeking.

So where is the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which file are actually taking care of "Logout" process? (killing sessions)](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15099/which-file-are-actually-taking-care-of-logout-process-killing-sessions)

Comment: This is a follow up question of that one. In there I get to know where session is destroyed, but stil don't know where global variable is received.

Answer (score 2):

Its received by [`JInput`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/input/input.php) which is instantiated in [`JApplicationBase::_construct()`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3b1562b3b17fabd1688c6805c6170c1090280cb6/libraries/joomla/application/base.php#L54).

By default it's source is `$_REQUEST` like you can see [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/22fdc98d5a8eed3cf40cebb310e7402d1fb0f1f0/libraries/joomla/input/input.php#L94).

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla, the POST,GET,REQUEST method is achieved through `jinput` .

Example Code:

`$jinput= JFactory::getApplication()->input;
 $data = $app->post->get('variablename','defaultvalue','filter');`

Refernce Link: https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

For logout method, a task is defined here:

`<input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.logout">`

Tasks are defined in master/sub-controllers which are basically functions.

For this go to `components/com_users/controllers/user.php`

In this file, you will find a `logout` function which performs the logout methodology.

Hope this helps